# How to group by one column, take max for each group, and retain information of the other groups?

Tags: sql, hive

I have data like this:

```
column1    column2   column3
A          V         10
A          Z         11
A          X         11
```

And for each data in `column1`I want to find the maximum value in `column3` and the corresponding value in `column2`.  How do I do this in `HIVE`?

The closest thing I have is to do `select column1, max(column3) from table group by column1`.  But, this doesn't add the corresponding information from `column2`.  How do I get that as well?

Upon a tie in column3, I really don't care which value we pull from `column2`.  Thanks.

I want the result to be:

```
column1   column2   column3
A         Z         11
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it would be using `row_number`. In case of ties, you would get an arbitrary value for column2.

```
select column1,column2,column3
from (
select t.*,row_number() over(partition by column1 order by column3 desc) as rn
from tablename t
) x
where rn=1
```

Comment: hm.  really there is no more elegant/shorter solution?  I'm just wondering.

Comment: The 2nd solution with row_number is fine, the 1st solution - not.

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz .. i was overthinking when i wrote the first query..i removed it as it may not work in Hive.

Comment: @vkp - It was just way complicated than needed

Answer (score 0):

Here are some variation of the same concept

---

```
select      column1           ,
           ,max(named_struct('column3',column3,'column2',column2)).column2
           ,max(column3) as column3

from        mytable

group by    column1
;
```

---

```
+---------+---------+---------+
| column1 | column2 | column3 |
+---------+---------+---------+
| A       | Z       |      11 |
+---------+---------+---------+
```

---

```
select      column1
           ,max(struct(column3,column2)).col2  as column2
           ,max(column3)                       as column3

from        mytable

group by    column1
;
```

---

```
+---------+---------+---------+
| column1 | column2 | column3 |
+---------+---------+---------+
| A       | Z       |      11 |
+---------+---------+---------+
```

---

```
select      column1
           ,col.column2
           ,col.column3

from       (select      column1
                       ,max(named_struct('column3',column3,'column2',column2)) as col

            from        mytable

            group by    column1
            ) t
;
```

---

```
+---------+---------+---------+
| column1 | column2 | column3 |
+---------+---------+---------+
| A       | Z       |      11 |
+---------+---------+---------+
```